# It is possible to make a changelog in code files using svn auto-props?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

There is a simple scenario (based on a .txt-file):

1. Creating mycodefile.txt, pasting the text to it and adding it to svn:

   ```
   $Id_which_is_populated_once_per_revision$ $Svn_commit_comments_but_also_populated_once$  
   I have added this in the revision #1.
   ```
2. Commiting the file with the comment "JIRA-1234". After commit the file will be as follows:

   ```
   $Id: mycodefile.txt 1 2013-07-29 12:05:30Z svnuser $ $Svncomments: JIRA-1234 $  
   I have added this in the revision #1.
   ```
3. Making another changes:

   ```
   $Id: mycodefile.txt 1 2013-07-29 12:05:30Z svnuser $ $Svncomments: JIRA-1234 $  
   $Id_which_is_populated_once_per_revision$ $Svn_commit_comments_but_also_populated_once$  
   I have added this in the revision #1.  
   And this in the revision #2.
   ```
4. Commiting the file with the comment "JIRA-2345". After commit the file will be as follows:

   ```
   $Id: mycodefile.txt 1 2013-07-29 12:05:30Z svnuser $ $Svncomments: JIRA-1234 $  
   $Id: mycodefile.txt 2 2013-07-29 12:07:45Z svnuser $ $Svncomments: JIRA-2345 $  
   I have added this in the revision #1.  
   And this in the revision #2.
   ```

And so on.
So that, after many changes I can still track them using only built-in comments without using svn revision log.
Currently, if I will use a simple $Id$ auto-prop, then the file on the step 4 will be as follows (overriding any previous $Id$s and comments):

```
$Id: mycodefile.txt 2 2013-07-29 12:07:45Z svnuser $ $Svncomments: JIRA-2345 $  
$Id: mycodefile.txt 2 2013-07-29 12:07:45Z svnuser $ $Svncomments: JIRA-2345 $  
I have added this in the revision #1.  
And this in the revision #2.
```

Besides, there is no $Svncomments$ auto-prop actually (I just made it to illustrate my desire).

So the question is how to implement the above (using auto-props or something else maybe)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. And it's a [bad idea](https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#log-in-source) to begin with.

If you need a changelog, generate one in your build/packaging process using output from `svn log`